# PHP How to add specific class to last echoed <li> in while loop

Tags: php

Echoing out results from a database in a while loop so that I can echo 5 of them out at once.
Currently have put a standard string into the loop in order to test. The `<li>` elements have a `border-bottom` attribute in their stylings.
Is it possible to have the last result echoed (number 5) to have another class applied that would rule out the border?

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 5) {
    // On the 5th, change the class here to rule out the border-bottom.
    echo "<li>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>";
    $i++;
}
```

So, somewhere in there, throw in an if statement?
Sorry. This could be really simple, but it's been a long day

Comment: Please make code easy to read for people trying to help you :)

Comment: @Fluffeh I appreciate my indents are a bit extreme tonight, but I don't see how that could be in any way difficult to read (:

Comment: I wasn't having a go at you at all, just a good part of the code was off the screen and needed scrolling to get to. To get the most sets of eyeballs looking at your question, it's best to make it as easy for folks to help you as possible. It only serves to get you better/more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use a simple check inside the loop and output depending on your counter?

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= 5)
    {
        if($i<5)
        {
            echo "<li>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li class='fluffeh'>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>"; 
        }
        // On the 5th, change the class here to rule out the border-bottom.
        $i++;
    }       
?>
```

Or if you wanted every fifth one different, you could do:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= 10)
    {
        if($i%5!=0)
        {
            echo "<li>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li class='fluffeh'>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>"; 
        }
        // On the 5th, change the class here to rule out the border-bottom.
        $i++;
    }       
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while($i <= 5){
    $class = "";
    if($i===5)
        $class = " class=\"last\"";
    echo "<li$class>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>"; // On the 5th, change the class here to rule out the border-bottom.
    $i++;
}
```

of course that this is a blind answer to a closed question, you would do greater if you follow  other people answers's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than always using the number five as a placeholder, it would probably be better to count the elements in the array, and if it's the last one, omit the line.

```
$elementsCount = count($elements);
for ($index = 0; $index < $elementsCount; ++$index) {
    $class = $index == $elementsCount - 1 ? 'lastElement' : 'standardElement';
    echo '
        <li class="', $class, '">', $elements[$index], '</li>';
}
```

Comment: That would be good, too. I'm using it for a 'latest x' kind of thing, though. So 5 results (obviously ordered by time) would be enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have already an counter, your variable $i. The variable $i which you count to know when reach 5th loop to end the loop.

Also you can use it for if- or other statments to do somethin in third or secend element or other stuff like, when $i counts 4 it should ouput other class or do a function or somenthing else.

All you have to do is to asking, when the 5 loop is reached insert an class:

```
<?php
  $class = null;
  $li_element = null;
  for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
  {
    if($i==5)
    {
      $class="last_element";
    }
    $li_element .= '<li '.$class.'>...</li>';
  }

  echo '<ul>'.$li_element.'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add to much lines to your code you could also do something like this:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i<= 5) {
    echo ($i < 5) ? "<li>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>" : "<li class='someclass'>jQuery &amp;HTML5 audio player.</li>";
    $i++;
}
```

Being "someclass" the style you want to apply to the last li.